Let's merge [speech], [spoken] and [speaking] into one tag
I feel the three tags speech (5 Qs), spoken (17 Qs), and speaking (41 Qs) are not meaningfully different, so I think we should merge them (creating suitable synonyms).  It seems natural to keep the speaking tag (kind of a "majority rules"), but perhaps oral-chinese or verbal-chinese is more precise.
Any preference as to what the final tag should be called?
For the record, the questions are:
speech

When can nouns be used as verbs?
Chinese Speaking Gps Tracker For My Dog, please help to translate
Website about talk /speech in Chinese
How do I improve Mandarin vocal conversation?
How do Chinese speakers convey emotions by speech?

spoken

How should I understand the absence of conjunctions in 流行音乐歌唱的大都是男女爱情、歌词贴近生活、通俗易懂、易于传唱、受到欢迎、不足为怪?
不要说话 vs 不说话 (vs 别说话)
What does 我知道 and 应该的 mean in this dialogue?
"easily fooled" in Chinese(slang)
Why native speakers always say "一块钱" and write "一元钱 "instead of "壹圆钱"？
Is 如果我们，所有的学生，没有我们的中文老师，我们就永远不能站起来在听众前面说中文 grammatical and does it makes sense?
Tone contours along diphthongs
When is a degree required? or: hai6 vs hou2 vs gei
How is 眷顾 used in spoken Chinese?
Pronunciation of Tang Dynasty Poetry
Is it correct to say the standard for written Chinese is Mandarin, regardless of dialect (e.g. Cantonese)?
"Today" in Spoken Singaporean Mandarin
welcoming a chinese delegation
Why so many definitions associated with each word?
How to wish people good health, etc during Chinese New Year 揮春 | 春貼 | 門聯、春仔
Proper way to use sentence-final particles (like 啦 or 喽) in spoken Chinese
How can I skip characters I can't read when reading aloud?

speaking

How to pronounce 學 "shwehh", "shoo-ehh", or "xüüehh"?
When speaking, how would one say "cannot study"? E.g. 不能学习 or 学习不了 or 无法学习
Accent on "dou1" (all) after a subject
Are the "h" in pinyin always pronounced as "[x]" in IPA?
Help with tones?
Curious about different ways of swearing in Mandarin
Where can I find a collection of samples of Mandarin spoken words, annotated with pinyin and tones?
Does pronouncing every word accurately make you sound less like a native speaker?
Does reading Chinese sentences improve my speaking?
Chinese Speaking Gps Tracker For My Dog, please help to translate
How is a speaker introduced at a Chinese mathematics conference?
Understanding how to pronounce the “er” at end of words
Is there any way to make a Chinese speech transcribed to written format?
几 in declarative and interrogative sentence
Is Southwestern Mandarin different from Mandarin?
How to hear tones in speech better
How to improve speaking skills during "real" conversations
Beginner learning Cantonese: Start with reading/writing or with speaking?
How do I tell the difference between "ing" and "in"?
In Cantonese, what is a less "childish" way to call one's own parents?
Where can I find people to communicate in Chinese to learn and improve it?
How to speak more naturally / like a native Chinese speaker
What is the difference between 好多 vs. 很多?
phrase for "It happened just as you finished talking about it"
How do you specify 她 in speech?
Tourists in China but can not understand Chinese
How can I find the exact written versions of commonly spoken Cantonese words?
Hong Kong Cantonese variations
When do you use 唄 instead of 吧 to end a sentence?
Describing a person that can speak Mandarin
How do Chinese spell English words over the phone?
Pronounce ellipsis 《●●● ●●●》 in Mandarin
Learning/remembering Chinese
Do acronyms borrowed from English use neutral tone (aka tone 0 or tone 5) for all syllables?
How can I improve the speed of my spoken Chinese?
What board games would facilitate speaking practice?
What software can correct pronunciation?
Why is 的 (de) sometimes pronounced "di" even though it is used as a possessive particle?
"Actually" as a sentence-starter of speech filler
Why do Chinese "extend" the last word when speaking?
Where to practice speaking Chinese?


i would prefer spoken, verbal, oral

I'm in favor of keeping [spoken], or merging into a new tag [spoken-language]

status-planned => I intend to do it (it looks like [spoken] is fine), but I'll wait a few days in case someone wants to discuss it further.

(I mentioned other tag changes I'm thinking about in chat.)

I went ahead and did it: there's now only the spoken tag.  I don't think this is remotely controversial.  Off the top of my head, I created the excerpt

For questions about spoken Chinese (aka "oral Chinese" or "verbal Chinese"); consider also the [pronunciation] tag.

But please edit this if you can improve it or think of a better one.
